# Ruby prints blank after writing lines

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to truncate and write new lines to the contents of a file and then print it:

```
target = File.open(ARGV.first, 'w')

puts "we are going to clear the file first"

target.truncate(0)

puts "give me 1 line"
line1 = $stdin.gets.chomp
puts "give me another line!"
line2 = $stdin.gets.chomp

puts "we are gonna write the text into the file now"
target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")

newfile = open(ARGV.first, 'r')
puts newfile.read

puts "we will close the file now"
target.close
```

However, Ruby keeps printing blank. The text file that I write to though, has the text that I entered. I'm not sure what is happening.

Comment: Even if it is empty, please post the output of your program **in the question body, not comments**. We cannot help without knowing the actual output vs expected output.

Comment: Second, I changed your tag. RoR is a web framework not focused on in LRTHW. Next time, please choose the _correct_ tags, which are not necessarily the most popular ones on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the file before you try to read from it.

```
target = File.open(ARGV.first, 'w')

puts "we are going to clear the file first"

target.truncate(0)

puts "give me 1 line"
line1 = $stdin.gets.chomp
puts "give me another line!"
line2 = $stdin.gets.chomp

puts "we are gonna write the text into the file now"
target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")

puts "we will close the file now"
target.close

newfile = open(ARGV.first, 'r')
puts newfile.read
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jarod! I'm curious to know the theory behind this -- why do I have to close the file first and what actually happens behind the code?